# how to solve migrate symfony 3.3 to 4 twig extension error?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I migrate my symfony project from 3.3 to 4, code by code (copy and paste).

I got error in my twig extension all error.

this is my config.yaml :

```
# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: 'en'
    brochures_directory: '%kernel.project_dir%/public/uploads/brochures'

services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        autowire: true      # Automatically injects dependencies in your services.
        autoconfigure: true # Automatically registers your services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        public: false       # Allows optimizing the container by removing unused services; this also means
                            # fetching services directly from the container via $container->get() won't work.
                            # The best practice is to be explicit about your dependencies anyway.

    # makes classes in src/ available to be used as services
    # this creates a service per class whose id is the fully-qualified class name
    App\:
        resource: '../src/*'
        exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'

    # controllers are imported separately to make sure services can be injected
    # as action arguments even if you don't extend any base controller class
    App\Controller\:
        resource: '../src/Controller'
        tags: ['controller.service_arguments']

    App\Twig\:
        resource: '../src/Twig'
        arguments:
            $doctrine : '@doctrine'
            $tokenStorage  : '@security.token_storage'
        tags:
          -  { name: twig.extension }
        autowire: true

    # add more service definitions when explicit configuration is needed
    # please note that last definitions always *replace* previous ones

    App\Service\FileUploader:
        arguments:
            $targetDirectory: '%brochures_directory%'
```

as you can see, i load every file twig extensions here :

```
App\Twig\:
    resource: '../src/Twig'
    arguments:
        $doctrine : '@doctrine'
        $tokenStorage  : '@security.token_storage'
    tags:
      -  { name: twig.extension }
    autowire: true
```

it work in 3.3 but not work in 4. Oh ya, this is example of my twig extension :

```
<?php

namespace App\Twig;

use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\RegistryInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\Storage\TokenStorageInterface;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFilter;

class TwigExtension extends \Twig_Extension
{
    protected $doctrine;
    protected $user;

    public function __construct(RegistryInterface $doctrine, TokenStorageInterface $tokenStorage)
    {
        $this->doctrine = $doctrine;

        if($tokenStorage->getToken() != null) {
            $this->user= $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        }
    }

    public function getFunctions() {
        return array(
            new TwigFilter('price', array($this, 'priceFilter'))
        );
    }

    public function priceFilter($number, $decimals = 0, $decPoint = '.', $thousandsSep = ',')
    {
        $price = number_format($number, $decimals, $decPoint, $thousandsSep);
        $price = '$'.$price;

        return $price;
    }

}
```

and I tried to call this filter :

```
<h1>{{ countProducts | price }}</h1>
```

this the ERROR :

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Syntax: "Unknown "price" filter."
```

how to solve this problem?
because it work in symfony 3.3 projects

Comment: In Symfony 4 you should extend `Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension`. [Read How to Write a custom Twig Extension](https://symfony.com/doc/4.0/templating/twig_extension.html)

Comment: I've tried change it to `SomeExtension extends AbstractExtension` but still not work

Comment: Did you try changing getFunctions to getFilters?

Comment: Please, read the documentation (_following the provided link_) and find all the differences with your code.

Comment: Okay I tried to re code, with the documentation as you suggest, and it works

Comment: Glad to help, but remember, the Tool's documentation is almost always your best friend, then Google and at last StackOverflow :-) PS: I'm not a "reputation hunter" so you can add an answer to help future users.